# why isn't there a "to" before "the" in "confidential treatment will be accorded the Confidential Information"?

Tags: grammar

I checked on google and it seems that there are a lot of usages like the quoted but is this grammatically right?

Comment: Ask yourself: ***what** will it be accorded?* the answer will be: *it will be accorded the confidential info*. I do not see a reason to write *to* before *the* in this context

Comment: Yes I see it and this is a special usage and case sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: What has case got to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

**accorded** can take either an object or a prepositional phrase complement. It is a so-called *di-transitive* verb.

> We accorded special treatment to them.
>
> We accorded them special treatment.

**them** is the entity which benefits from the action, that is, the receiver or recipient or beneficiary of the benefit.

**special treatment** is the benefit, that which is (duly) given or accorded.

When those sentences are recast in the passive:

> Special treatment was accorded to them by us.
>
> Special treatment was accorded them by us.
>
> Special treatment was accorded to them.
>
> Special treatment was accorded them.
>
> They were accorded special treatment by us.
>
> They were accorded special treatment.

Answer (score 1):

'Accorded' and 'accorded to' are both equally correct. Following the verb with 'to' is optional.